# sin function not working as expected

Tags: c

I have this equation its output using a sci calc is : 0.017... but when i run it in c its output is :0.84..

The input is 1

Equation is: sin(x) - x^4 + 1

```
float sinp(float p1)
{
    float fop;
    float ppowers;
    printf("%f",p1);
    ppowers = pow(p1,4);
    fop = sin(p1)-ppowers+1;
    return (fop);
}
```

is there a reason behind this like would it be because of rad or in degree?

I havent really used the sin or any math function of C that much so I don't really get whats wrong here. Google gave me .84 as an aswer but my calc gives me .017 which is really confusing since I need to get the same output with my calc.

Thank you all :)

Comment: What is the input for which you get the output you write?

Comment: @WernerHenze sorry forgot to write that.

Comment: @magicianalarm: So your equation is down to y=sin(1). As you can check with a calculator sin(1)==0.017... for degrees (0..360) and sin(1)==0.84... for radians (0..2*PI). Your sci calculator is calculating with degrees, C library sin is calculating with radians.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing google uses degrees as angle measure in sin, while c++ uses radians and that is the reason for the difference. To convert an angle in degrees to same value in radians to the following:

```
rad_angle = deg_angle * (PI / 180.0);
```

Where `PI` it the good old constant you know.

Comment: But don't write PI = 3.14 . Use `M_PI` from `<math.h>` which is as accurate as possible.

Comment: @zch several times I had compilation issues using that one so I usually copy past the value accurate up to 12 digits from a calculator and use a `const double PI = 3.14159265359`

Comment: thank you for this, i didnt knew about that, i should have read more on the docu part.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Perhaps you're using a Microsoft compiler?  If so, you may need to `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES` before you include `<math.h>`.  Then your math constants should be available. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hwaceh6(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: The code shown in this answer causes an unnecessary division each time it is executed, and division is a slow operation. Rewriting it as `deg_angle * (PI / 180.)` allows the compiler to compute the division at compile time, provided `PI` is a compile-time constant.

Comment: google uses radians and c++ uses radians. It's the the pocket calc which is more biased towards highschool mathematics.

Answer (score 4):

In mathemtics and in all computer languages trigonometric functions work in radians. If you want to work in degrees you should make the conversion (or define your own sin_degrees function) like:

```
double sin_degrees(double degrees) {
    return sin(degrees * (M_PI/180.0);
}
```